# How to split a column when there is a weird/no space

Tags: r, split

Here is the `head()`:

[image]

Here is the `View()`:

[image]

I want to split Ensemblnames and Gene names into 2 different columns.
I don´t really understand how I can let it split by "\" or if there are other options to split it.

What I tried

```
df i<-
  tidyr::separate(
    data = df,
    col = Ensemblnames,
    sep = " \ ",
    into = colmn,
    remove = FALSE)
```

```
Error in UseMethod("separate") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: It seems like your data is name `Ensemblnames`, not `df`. Make sure to use the right name in `separate(data=)`

Comment: You could try `[[:space:]]` or `\\s` as separator.

Comment: In the `head` view, we can see `\t` which is a tab character. Backslashes need escaping so `sep = "\\t"` would probably work, as should the default if you don't specify `sep` at all. But probably your data was read in incorrectly--rather than separating it now you could go back to the command you used to read in the data and use a tab separator (the default for `readr::read_tsv`)  and then it would be correct from the start.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you need?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

##### Data

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
           ~gene_id.gene_name,
   "ENSG00000000003\tTSPAN6",
      "ENSG00000000005\tTND",
     "ENSG00000000419\tDPM1",
     "ENSG00000000457\tSCYL3",
  "ENSG00000000460\tc1orf112",
       "ENSG00000000938\tFGR"
  )
```

#### solution

```r
df %>% 
  separate(col = gene_id.gene_name, into = c("a", "b"), sep = "\t")
```

rename `"a"` and `"b"` for the new column names you want.

#### output

```r
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   a               b       
#>   <chr>           <chr>   
#> 1 ENSG00000000003 TSPAN6  
#> 2 ENSG00000000005 TND     
#> 3 ENSG00000000419 DPM1    
#> 4 ENSG00000000457 SCYL3   
#> 5 ENSG00000000460 c1orf112
#> 6 ENSG00000000938 FGR
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>